# Render view as result of POST request in Express

Tags: node.js, express, post, get

I have a basic node app which is integrated with stripe. The client-side javascript generates a token which is sent in a POST request to the server. The server then sends the stripe API the token which makes the payment. I want to redirect the user to a page showing some info e.g. Payment successful or Error making payment.

When I put `res.render("/charge", {<some-JSON>});` in the code that handles the POST request, it sends the page `/charge` as a response to the POST request. Is there a way to send the user a page as a response instead of sending the POST request the response?

Node Snippet:

```
app.post(req, res) {
    // Some Code
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, but if you don't want to send the user the /charge page and only send back the contents of the post request, then use `res.json(yourObject);`

Comment: What I would like to do, is the exact oposite of your reply: send the user the /charge page and not the json

Comment: How are you declaring your endpoints? With `app.post()`?

Comment: Correct. I will add that to my question.

Comment: If you want to both access the endpoint via the browser (`GET`) and `POST` data to it, use `app.use()` instead.

Comment: Can you give an example of how this might be done?

Comment: `app.use('/yourendpointhere', function(req, res) {
    // Some Code
  res.render("/charge", {<some-JSON>});
});`

Comment: How would I incorporate the GET and POST requests?

Comment: How would I only render /charge with a POST request?

Comment: `req.method`, will have which method you are using. You can use it to run conditional logic.

Comment: Please can you provide a full example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather from your post and comments. You are looking for a way to display Stripe response data into your webpage.

Instead of doing your traditional AJAX request with client-side JavaScript, use a form to submit the data to your server-side.

```
<form action="/stripe" method="post">
  <input type="text" value="whatever" name="batman">
  <button type="submit">Pay</button>
</form>
```

On your server-side, create an endpoint, using `app.use('/stripe')`, as an example, but the endpoint has to match your value in the `action=""` attribute. Then simply render the page with the stripe response.

```
app.use('/stripe', function(req, res) {
  // whatever code
  res.render('/charge', {JS OBJECT});
});
```